# Regarding Image Processing - nlfilter, blockproc, colfilt

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm currently running a script that requires a sliding window through an image. For each window, I have to compute the histogram equalization to apply to it.
It says that:

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts.
```

I believe its possible to run `nlfilter` with a sliding window based on `histeq` from each window, but I just cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: hi rayryeng thanks for the reply. Yep looks like histeq seems impossible to be implemented by nlfilter or colfilt in that case, the array nature of histeq will not work for either or them. i guess then blockproc will be the only choice i have, using a larger window. thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem.  If I wrote an answer describing this, would you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting that `nlfilter` error is because histogram equalization outputs an **image**. For each pixel location in your image, `nlfilter` processes a neighbourhood surrounding this pixel and a **single output pixel** is produced. For this reason, `nlfilter` cannot be used. `colfilt` operates the same way, but it takes pixel neighbourhoods, reshapes them into single columns, and we filter each column separately.  The output for each column is a **single pixel**, and `colfilt` then reshapes the output so that it is an image again and that's the output. As such, this answers your question about `colfilt`!

For applying `histeq` locally, I can only see this working if the blocks are non-overlapping and so your `blockproc` code should work. A sliding window (overlapping) approach would not work as your output would be image blocks, not single pixels. I would assume that you would replace each block in the image with its `histeq`'d version?  In that case, using `blockproc` is very natural.

Also, if we did `histeq` on a sliding window, we would have multiple blocks overlapping each other. How would you combine all of them? Also, you're getting bad results because the window size is too small. `histeq` is designed to increase contrast, and by applying histogram equalization on such a small window, you would blow out the contrast of each local window, and the combination of all of this would make the image look really noisy. In your code, you specified a patch size of 3 x 3.  With this, you would have 3 x 3 patches of black and white because there is very little variation in such a small sized window, thus leading to a smaller number of intensities.  With such a small amount of intensities, the output block would inevitably be pushed to black and white.

Try increasing the window size to something a lot bigger (like 31 x 31) and see what you get!

Comment: yep! looks like the increased window size produecd much better results! thanks for the in depth explanantion rayryeng! =)